# WebRTC Video & PSTN integration

Tags: webrtc, twilio, telephony, opentok, tokbox

This is a broad question - are there any solutions to WebRTC Video & PSTN integration ? The requirements are:

1. Multi-party WebRTC video conference (SFU or MCU, not peer to peer)
2. Ability to join the conference via PSTN end points (telephones) - obviously with audio fallback
3. Prefer paid service (like Tokbox or Twilio) rather than roll-your-own solution

We *are* currently using TokBox, however, it does not provide a PSTN integration. Since the call signalling is entirely hidden under the TokBox API, it seems unlikely that we could add (some kind of) WebRTC to PSTN gateway and make it work. Twilio has a video offering but it's actually in a very infant stage right now (peer to peer only, it seems with a limit of 4 participants).

Since we a Web App company and not a infrastructure company, I'd prefer a solution that handles the infrastructure part (like TokBox and Twilio do), but am open to other solutions as well, if that's what it'll take.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Avinash,

Twilio [Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video) does not currently support PSTN integration. And there is currently that 4 participant limit regarding video chat.

This product is still a beta and constantly evolving so I'd suggest [this group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/twilio-programmable-video-sdk-releases) to you for keeping up with the updates.